# Firebase/Admob installation guide with pods on Cocoapods site vs Firebase installation guide on google

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, admob

I'm trying to integrate firebase/admob ads for ios app using Cocoapods. 
On Cocaopods site there is a guide such as downloading Cocoapods first then creating a pod file in the app and adding a code using pods. On Google site there are also instructions on how to install firebase ads sdk using pods but then it seems that I also need to insert coding such as gad etc in the actual application. I'm new to this, so I'm a bit confused - is Cocoapods coding enough or do I also need to add coding in the application as well in terms of initializing ads or creating buttons for specific ads such as banner/interstitial etc?

Comment: CocoaPods is a dependency manager. You'll need to add the pertinent code in your app to configure the library correctly (e.g: your app id). Follow the steps described in https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some coding in the app as well such that importing the Googlemobileads in the app delegate and configuring it in the func didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "Your application id")
```

and then adding the below code in your first controller or the controller in which you want to show the adds:

```
var bannerView: GADBannerView!    
bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
bannerView.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - bannerView.frame.size.height
self.view.addSubview(bannerView)
bannerView.adUnitID = "Your ad unit id"
bannerView.rootViewController = self
bannerView.load(GADRequest())
```

Comment: Thank you. My problem is that when I try to add coding that is also the case with instructions from admob website I'm not able to get anything done unless I start the coding with "//" at the beginning. Otherwise I get a message that "firebase" (if I use import firebase) or other file not found (with the red exclamation mark) (?)

Comment: You have to install pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' and then import Googlemobileads not firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I think the code is in C that's why I had problems with it and not Swift. I've managed to get almost everything done - I have a problem when I use self.bannerView and also GADBannerView with messages that it hasn't been declared previously. I tried to follow Objective C because that's how the code looks like, but don't seem to be able to resolve this.